# node.js express-session + redis single instance issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication, promise

I'm using express-session module to handle my node.js user sessions.
By default it allows multiple sessions per user. I need limit one session per user. I came to the following solution: store user_id:session_id pairs in redis, when user logins check if session for that user_id exists and delete it then create a new one and save it to redis. Everything works excellent until I tried to stress test my server using siege. I emulated simultaneous 1000 login attempts and I see that some sessions are not cleared and still is in redis store.

This allow one user have several sessions. What am I doing wrong?
Please find some code below.

```
 var FileStreamRotator = require('file-stream-rotator'),
    app = require('express')(),
    fs = require("fs"),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    config = require("./providers/config"),
    morgan = require('morgan'), //HTTP request logger middleware for node.js
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    redis = require('redis'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session),
    publicRouter = require('./routes/public.js')();

var port = process.env.PORT || config.port; 
var client = redis.createClient();

app.disable('x-powered-by'); 

app.use(cookieParser(config.session.secret));
app.use(session(
    {
        secret: config.session.secret,
        store: new redisStore({host: config.redis.host, port: config.redis.port, client: client}),
        saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored,
        resave: false // don't save session if unmodified
    }
));

app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());


*****
app.all('/api/*', [require('./middlewares/validateRequest')]);

******
app.use('/api/public', publicRouter); 
******

app.listen(port, function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('Find me on port ' + port + ' and say "Hello"');
    else console.log(err);
});
```

auth.js

```
var User = require('./../models/user.js');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var redis = require("./../providers/redis.js");
var util = require('util');

var auth = {
    login: function (req, res) {
        var login = req.body.login || '';
        var password = req.body.password || '';

        if (login === '') {
            res.status(401);
            res.json({
                "status": 401,
                "message": "login required"
            });
            return;
        }
        if (password === '') {
            res.status(401);
            res.json({
                "status": 401,
                "message": "password required"
            });
            return;
        }
        User.login(login, password)
            .then(function (user) {
                if (!user) {
                    res.status(401);
                    res.json({
                        "status": 401,
                        "message": "Incorrect login data."
                    });
                }

                return redis.get(util.format("usersess:%s", user.id))
                    .then(function (currentSession) {
                        if (currentSession === null) {
                            redis.set(util.format("usersess:%s", user.id), req.session.id)
                                .then(function () {
                                    delete user.password;
                                    req.session.user = user;
                                    res.json({
                                        "status": 200,
                                        "message": "User successfully logged in."
                                    });
                                });
                        } else {
                            if (currentSession !== req.session.id) {
                                return redis.del(util.format("sess:%s", currentSession))
                                    .then(function () {
                                        return redis.set(util.format("usersess:%s", user.id), req.session.id);
                                    })
                                    .then(function () {
                                        delete user.password;
                                        req.session.user = user;
                                            res.json({
                                                "status": 200,
                                                "message": "User successfully logged in."
                                            });
                                    })
                            } else {
                                res.json({
                                    "status": 200,
                                    "message": "User successfully logged in."
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    })
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500);
                res.json({
                    error: true,
                    data: {
                        message: err.message
                    }
                });
            });
    },


    logout: function (req, res) {
        req.session.destroy(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Can't destroy the session. See details below");
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500);
                res.json({
                    "status": 500,
                    "message": err.message
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200);
                res.json({
                    "status": 200,
                    "message": "User successfully logged out."
                })
            }
        });
    }
};

module.exports = auth;
```

user model user.js

```
 var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt')),
    db = require("./../providers/db.js");


var User = {
    tableName: 'users',

    login: function (login, password) {
        if (!login || !password) throw new Error('login and password are both required');
        return db.execStoredProcedure("user_get_by_login", [login.trim()])
            .then(
            function (rows) {
                var user = rows[0][0];
                return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, user.password)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        if (!res) user = null;
                        return user;
                    });
            }
        );
    }
};

module.exports = User;
```

redis provider redis.js

```
var config = require('./../providers/config');
var Promise = require("bluebird"),
    redis = require('promise-redis')(function(resolver) {
        return new Promise(resolver);
    }),
    redisClient = redis.createClient(config.redis.port, config.redis.host),
    util = require('util');

redisClient.on('connect', function () {
    console.log(util.format('redis connected on %s:%s', config.redis.host, config.redis.port));
});

module.exports = redisClient;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find the exact reason why some sessions are not deleted but after a lot of debugging and logs investigating I think it is due to node async nature. While mySQL getting operation require some time, some login actions could run in parallel and get the same values for current user session_id.
To solve this, I created middleware that check if current user session id is in redis store, if it is not--it just destroys the session and logout user asking for a new login attempt. This may be not a good solution but it completely solved the original issue.